# How to page through issues for a given project in Ruby

Tags: json, ruby, jira

How do I loop through all of the issues for a given project? Say I am doing something like this:

```
project = client.Project.find('SAMPLEPROJECT')
project.issues.each do |issue|
puts "#{issue.id} - #{issue.summary}"
end
```

project.issues returns only the first 50 and I'm unsure how to get the next 50 and so on.

Here is a link to the gem: **https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby**

Comment: What does the `Project` represent? What does the `find()` method return? List, hash, tuple? Is it specific to some library/class that `client` object is or a general Python question?

Comment: Sorry if my question was vague. It's my first time here :) I have edited my question. Please let me know if I need anything else to make my post clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the Github page you supplied I see in the actual code and option called :max_results. Setting this should do the trick if you know how much results you want to see (if there are huge amounts of issue querying them all at once will might not be the best idea).

If the :max_results option isn't actually implemented you might try any of the following solutions:

> project = client.Project.find('SAMPLEPROJECT&StartAt=51')

This will show the next 50 results and so on.
Or

> project = client.Project.find('SAMPLEPROJECT&maxResults=250')

Which as you already guessed provides the amount of results you point out.

Source: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/39128076/how-to-get-more-than-50-issues-with-search-api

Hope this helps